# Get Controls of a type and name

Tags: c#, arrays, controls

I have an array of contols (`TextBox`) that gets all the TextBoxes on the form.

```
TextBox[] title = MView.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToArray();
```

Is it possible to select them by name as well?

For example, if I wanted to select all TextBoxes that contained "title" in the name, and passed it into the `title` array, then select all the TextBoxes that contained "data" in the name, and pass that into a separate `data` array?

**NOTE:** I'm not referring to the *text* containing "title" or "data", but the *name* of the TextBoxes. I.e. `txtTitle01` or `txtData01`

Comment: You can access the `Controls` collection by the both by the variable (names) and the `Name` strings of the controls. However you need to understand the __difference__: `txtTitle01`  is __not__ the `Name` of the control! It is the name of a __variable__ that points to the control.  More than one variables can point to the same `Control`.. - `Name` is a __string property__ similar to `Text` that needs not to be unique and can be changed at any time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Where` extension method of `LINQ`

```
TextBox[] title = MView.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(d=>d.Name.Contains("title")).ToArray();
```

Also you can add multiple condition

```
TextBox[] title = MView.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(d=>d.Name.Contains("title") || d.Name.Contains("data")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, the you need the array of textboxes, it is good practice to name the array as titles instead of title. You can use the Where condition and Lambda expression in order to filter the controls.

For titles: Retrieve the controls with names containing "title"

```
TextBox[] titles = MView.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(c=>c.Name.Contains("title")).ToArray();
```

For data: Retrieve the controls with names containing "data"

```
TextBox[] data = MView.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(c=>c.Name.Contains("data")).ToArray();
```